# Access Violation(Segmentation Fault )

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, segmentation-fault

I have two classes (appointment, schedule), and a driver (main).

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "schedule.h"
#include "appointment.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    schedule mySch2("hello");

    appointment myAppt(100002,"appointment",10,1,2013);
    myAppt.printS(cout,2);

    mySch2.addtoSchedule(myAppt);


    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

schedule.h

```
#ifndef SCHEDULE_H
#define SCHEDULE_H

#include<iostream>
#include "appointment.h"

using namespace::std;
const int SCH_ENTRIES = 10;
class schedule
{
      public:
             schedule(void);
             schedule(const char *p);
             bool addtoSchedule(const appointment &);

      private:
              char title[40];
              int count;
              appointment appointmentArray[SCH_ENTRIES];
};
#endif
```

schedule.cpp

```
#include "schedule.h"
#include "appointment.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace::std;

schedule::schedule(void)
{
}
schedule::schedule(const char *p)
{
    strcpy(title, p);
    count = 0;
    cout << title << endl;
    cout << count << endl;
    cout << "----" << endl;
}

bool schedule::addtoSchedule(const appointment & myAppt)
{
    cout << appointmentArray[0].getDay();
    return false;
}
```

appointment.h (I did not write this, this was provided) - not super important for this question

```
#ifndef APPOINTMENT_H
#define APPOINTMENT_H

    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstring>

    using std::ostream;

    //  The Designer decides upon the following data and actions (i.e. Functions)
    //  and places the class in the file appointment.h

    class appointment
    {
        public:

            appointment(void);                                              // default constructor
            appointment(long, const char [],int d, int m, int y);           // 5 argument constructor
            appointment(const appointment &);                               // copy constructor

            void keyBoardInput(void);                                       // Assume no blanks in the desc

            long getSource(void) const;                                     // return source
            void setSource(long);                                           // change source

            void setMonth(int);
            void setDay(int);
            void setYear(int);

            int getMonth(void) const;
            int getDay(void) const;
            int getYear(void) const;

            const char *getDescription(void) const;                         // return the address of the description
            void changeDescription(const char *) ;                          // change an existing description

            void copyTo(appointment &) const;                               // copy invoking instance to parameter

            void incrementDate (void);                                      // advance the date by ONE day
                                                                            // You can assume 30 days in each month

            void printS(ostream &, int dateFormat) const;   // print all fields
            // dateFormat == 1   month/day/year
            // dateFormat == 2   day/month/year

            ~appointment();               // destructor - indicate the address
                                          //    of the variable that is leaving

            private:

            void setDescription(const char *);  //  used to allocated memory

            // data
            long source;          // id of the person scheduling the appointment
            char * desc;          // description of the appointment - Dynamic Data

            int  day;             // day, month, and year when the appointment
            int  month;           // will happen
            int  year;
    };

#endif
```

appointment.cpp (I did not write this, this was provided) - not super important for this question

```
#include "appointment.h"

#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

appointment::appointment()
{
    day = 0;
    cout << "default appt\n";
}

appointment::appointment(long lSource, const char cDescription[], int d, int m, int y)
{
    source = lSource;
    day = d;
    month = m;
    year = y;
    setDescription(cDescription);
}
appointment::appointment(const appointment & aToCopy)
{
    source = aToCopy.getSource();
    day = aToCopy.getDay();
    month = aToCopy.getMonth();
    year = aToCopy.getYear();
    setDescription(aToCopy.getDescription());
}


void appointment::setDescription(const char * cSource)
{
    if (desc != NULL) free (desc);

    if (cSource == NULL)
        return;

    desc = (char *)malloc (strlen (cSource) + 1);
    strcpy(desc, cSource);
}

long appointment::getSource(void) const
{
     return source;
}

void appointment::setSource(long lSource)
{
     source = lSource;
}

void appointment::setMonth(int iMonth)
{
     month = iMonth;
}

void appointment::setDay(int iDay)
{
     day = iDay;
}

void appointment::setYear(int iYear)
{
     year = iYear;
}

int  appointment::getMonth(void) const
{
     return month;
}

int  appointment::getDay(void)   const
{
     return day;
}

int  appointment::getYear(void)  const
{
     return year;
}

//return the address of the description
const char * appointment::getDescription(void) const
{
     return desc;
}

//change an existing description
void appointment::changeDescription(const char * cDescription)
{
    setDescription(cDescription);
}

void appointment::copyTo(appointment &p) const
{
    p.source = source;
    p.day = day;
    p.month = month;
    p.year = year;
    p.setDescription(desc);
}

void appointment::incrementDate(void)
{
    int days;

    switch (month)
    {
        case 1: // Jan: 31 Days
        case 3: // Mar: 31 Days
        case 5: // May: 31 Days
        case 7: // Jul: 31 Days
        case 10: // Oct: 31 Days
        case 12: // Dec: 31 Days
            days = 31;
            break;

        case 4: // Apr: 30
        case 6: // Jun: 30
        case 8: // Aug: 30
        case 9: // Sep: 30
        case 11: // Nov: 30
            days = 30;
            break;

        case 2: // Feb: 28/29 Days (Depends on year modulus 4 a modulus 100).
            days = !(year % 4) || !(year % 100) ? 29 : 28;
            break;
    }

    day++;

    if (day > days)
    {
        month++;
        day = 1;

        if (month > 12)
        {
            month = 1;
            year++;
        }
    }
}

void appointment::printS(ostream &out, int dateFormat) const
{
    if (dateFormat == 1)
    {
        out << month << "/" << day << "/" << year << "\n";
    }
    else if (dateFormat == 2)
    {
        out << day << "/" << month << "/" << year << "\n";
    }
    else
        out << "Unsupported dateFormat parameter specified (should be 1 or 2).";
}

appointment::~appointment()
{
    if (desc != NULL)
    {
        free (desc);
        desc = NULL;
    }
}

void appointment::keyBoardInput()
{
    char temp[1024];

    cout << "Please type the description: ";
    cin.getline (temp, sizeof(temp) - 1, '\n');
    cout << std::endl;

    setDescription(temp);
}
```

My error occurs when the main driver calls mySch2.addtoSchedule(myAppt);

If I uncomment out the line inside of schedule appointmentArray[0].getDay() then everything runs and works fine with no segmentation error. As soon as that line gets uncommented, it throws the error during runtime (after a crash and I go into the debugger and step through the program).

Comment: Some other part of the program must be corrupting memory. Segmentation violation is caused by pointer misuse, and you're not using any pointers in that part of the code. Have you tried using valgrind to catch memory problems?

Comment: That is the entire code :( I am not sure what valgrind is

Comment: Valgrind is a tool for debugging memory management problems, which is exactly what you're having.

Comment: can you put a breakpoint on the line `appointmentArray[0].getDay()` and check the elements of the array?

Comment: breakpoint added on the cout << appointmentArray[0].getDay() line, added watch of appointmentArray[0]. Result is this->appointmentArray[0] source = 16777216, desc = 0x0, day = 0, month = 0, year = 2686372

Comment: now, I know only day was provided when the default appointments are filled into the array when appointmentArray is created

Comment: You're using `appointmentArray[0]` but you never assign to it. It seems like something the `addtoSchedule()` function should be doing. Why does a function named `addtoSchedule` just print out an element of the schedule that has never been filled in?

Comment: Because when I first wrote the entire class, i had this error, so i started from scratch and started testing it one function at a time, adding in one variable at a time to try and catch the error. If i take out the appointmentArray[0].getDay() and replace it with appointmentArray[0] = myAppt the same thing happens :( - also, installed valgrind, but im on windows OS and unsure how to run it

Comment: When you setDescription, you should set `desc = NULL` after you free.

Comment: TY TY , appreciate everyones help and input on the problem. A silly overlooking on my part, and a simple NULL declaration has made hours of pondering resolved! Thank you all bunches!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never initialize `desc` to `nullptr` for class `appointment` before invoking `setDescription`. This happens in both constructors. Learn to use an initializer list:

```
appointment::appointment()
    : source(), desc(), day(), month(), year()
{
    cout << "default appt\n";
}

appointment::appointment(long lSource, const char cDescription[], int d, int m, int y)
    : source(lSource), desc(), day(d), month(m), year(y)
{
    setDescription(cDescription);
}

appointment::appointment(const appointment & aToCopy)
    : source(aToCopy.getSource())
    , desc()
    , day(aToCopy.getDay())
    , month(aToCopy.getMonth())
    , year(aToCopy.getYear())
{
    setDescription(aToCopy.getDescription());
}
```

**Why did it fault?**

Without initialization the value in `desc` is indeterminate and therefore **undefined behavior** to dereference, and certainly so to pass to `free`.

```
void appointment::setDescription(const char * cSource)
{
    if (desc != NULL) free (desc); // desc contains non-null garbage.

    if (cSource == NULL)
        return;

    desc = (char *)malloc (strlen (cSource) + 1);
    strcpy(desc, cSource);
}
```

That said,  I would strongly encourage using a `std::string` instead. It would make the copy-consructor for this class completely disappear, and the default constructor trivial.

Comments about using `malloc()` in a C++ program reserved, as that opinion is all-but beat to death already on this forum (and I agree with te prevailing opinion).

Comment: Ahhh, as I said the appointment class was provided so I really didn't think to look at it too strongly. Although, setting it to null really never crossed my mind either. I appreciate all the helps and the explanation as well. I will also check more into std::string since you mention it, as it is something I haven't had a whole lot of experience with yet (I am still rather new at C++, and was under the impression vector was better? I'll just look at them both!). Not sure how much I am able to deviate from the provided code, but setting to null fixed the problem so I am super happy ^_^ ty again